# Extract sheet name and criteria from COUNTIF function in excel

Tags: excel, vba, countif

Hi I have a COUNTIF formula:
`RawData_Chq!G2:G5000,"*ICS*"`
. Using VBA, I would like to be able to extract the sheetname: RawData_Chq in 1 string and the criteria ICS in another. 
How I should I go about it ?

```
Dim formula_extract As String
Dim CI_Name As String
Dim ButtonName As String
Dim CI_Extract As String
Dim Sheet_Extract As String
Dim Split_Formula() As String
ButtonName = Application.Caller
 Set b = ActiveSheet.Buttons(ButtonName)
  r = b.TopLeftCell.Row
  CI_Name = Cells(r, 2).Value
 formula_extract = Cells(r, 3).Formula
Split_Formula = Split(formula_extract, ",")

 Sheet_Extract = Left(Split_Formula(0), InStr("!", Split_Formula(0)))
 CI_Extract = Split_Formula(1)
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us the code of what you have tried so far so we can be able to help you.

Comment: split the formula in to an array and parse the items, or just use the `Left` and `Right` functions to parse the formula string from the comma that separates the formulas two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it I think, it's just a matter of splitting the formula in to its individual elements and then parsing those to remove any unneeded data:

```
CI_Name = Cells(r, 2).Value
formula_extract = [A1].Formula
Split_Formula = Split(formula_extract, ",")

Dim functionString As String
'Use this later to get rid of these characters with the sheet_extract
functionString = "=COUNTIF("

'The worksheet name:
Sheet_Extract = Left(Split_Formula(0), InStr(Split_Formula(0), "!") - 1)
Sheet_Extract = Replace(Sheet_Extract, functionString, vbNullString)

'The criteria:
CI_Extract = Split_Formula(1)
```

Comment: When I run the code, I am getting blank value in Sheet_Extract and my CI_Extract is "* ICS *". I only require ICS and not the * or ". How should I get that to happen? I have updated the code so you can see what I am running.

Comment: Also Split_Formula(0) equals "=COUNTIF(RawData_Chq!G2:G5000"

Comment: Use the `Replace` function to get rid of characters that you don't want, like the asterisk and quotation marks.

Comment: It's gonna be like an hour or so before I can come back to this but I will fix the Sheet_Extract if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I have figured out how to extract the CI by removing the asterisk and quotation marks. I Haven't been able to extract the Sheet Name yet. I'll wait till you are free. Thank you

Comment: I had the arguments to the Instr function in the wrong order, also need to remove the formula name itself, I'll revise momentarily :)